# How to virtualize a dedicated server

Tags: virtualization

I have a dedicated server with the following configuration :

```
CPU             : AMD Opteron 4386
Cores/threads   : 8c/8t 
Fréquence/burst : 3,1 GHz+/3,5 GHz+
RAM             : 64 Go DDR3 ECC 1066MHz
Disques Durs    : 2x 3 To SATA3
```

And i want virtualize it so i wanna know wich software you advise me 
 and how can i do that if any tutorial link of if u can make one here.

Thanks for help

Comment: We do not do product recommendations here as per site FAQ. Maybe spend an hour doing basic research yourself? That server is, btw., quite unsuitable for virtualization with that ridiculously low performance storage system. I would suggest starting 64mb ram either with only ssd or with something like 8 velcicpators in a Rad 10 for the virtual machines - and even then it will be slow during heavy operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Linux I have had great experiences using Vmware ESXI 5.x. It has great documentation and many companies are using it. If you want to use Windows it would probably be more wise to use Hyper-V in terms of licenses. With a server 2012 standard license you can use 2 vm's for free and with the Datacenter Edition you can have unlimited virtual instances deployed.

Vmware: http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.solutions.doc%2FGUID-0A264828-3933-4F4F-82D7-B5006A90CDBA.html

Hyper-V: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846766.aspx

Comment: Can you explain the license issue a bit more?

Comment: Windows server 2012 R2 is using a licensing model that allows a windows host to have virtual machines using the host license. Standard edition can have 2 virtual machines inherit the license. Datacenter edition can have unlimited virtual machines inherit the license.